# AddDays is LINQ to SQL

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq

I am trying to user the AddDays function in LINQ to SQL inside the Where clause.

I need to return all the results that are greater than the current date plus a user defined range.

Here is my code.

```
Where (DateTime.Now >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(UserEnteredDaysToAdd)
```

What am I doing wrong? or is it even possible?

Thank you,

**Edit:**
Sorry I made a mistake. I want to get all the records that are in between the current date and an number of days the user enters or is stored in the db.

So it should read, Where (StockOrderDate >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(UserEnteredDaysToAdd))

Comment: Shouldn't DateTime.Now instead be a reference to a property/field of an object of your list?

Answer (score 2):

Lets have a look at your query:

```
Where (DateTime.Now >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(UserEnteredDaysToAdd))
```

Apart from not having the right body, you're checking if today is greater or equal to today plus x days. That won't ever be true if you do not allow negative values for `UserEnteredDaysToAdd`.

Your data structure (result) must have some date property you want to check for, like `ResultDate`, then your query would look like

```
IEnumerable<ResultType> results;
...
var resultsAfterDate = results.Where(r => r.ResultDate >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(UserEnteredDaysToAdd));
```